# I want to fix margin of my UIView with PDF View in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, pdfview

I am working on iOS pdf editor app, I have draw the pdf view inside the UIView , I gave same aspect ratio to both but there is padding/ margin between pdf view and UI View. I want to remove that padding space.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the answer. we have to have the pdfView aspect Fit